# Missing ',' separator after Swift 3 migration for method swizzle

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm having trouble converting the code below to Swift 3 syntax:

```
extension UIView {


    override public static func initialize() {
        if !didEAInitialize {
            replaceAnimationMethods()
            didEAInitialize = true
        }
    }

    private static func replaceAnimationMethods() {
        //replace actionForLayer...
        method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIView.actionForLayer(_:forKey:))),
            class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_actionForLayer(_:forKey:))))

        //replace animateWithDuration...
        method_exchangeImplementations(
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)(_:animations:))),
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:animations:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)(_:animations:completion:))),
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:animations:completion:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)(_:delay:options:animations:completion:))),
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:delay:options:animations:completion:))))
        method_exchangeImplementations(
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:)(_:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:))),
           class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:))))

    }

}
```

The code above is after running the migration tool. For example I originally had:

```
method_exchangeImplementations(
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animateWithDuration(_:animations:))),
            class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.EA_animateWithDuration(_:animations:))))
```

But now on the second line I get the error `Expected ',' separator` for `class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)(_:animations:)))`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The migration tool is not always perfect. Just make the first line look like the second line but without the `EA_` prefix. Change

```
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:)(_:animations:))),
```

to

```
class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:))),
```

and so on...

Comment: Did this and the errors have gone but now every second line has the `Expected ',' separator` error

Comment: @matt I think you need another parentheses before `,`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!

Comment: @SamM Sharp eyes! Thanks